# External Lookup Field Displayed as Textbox Instead of Lookup Input

Tags: externalobjects, external-lookup

I have a custom object which has two external lookup fields to two different external objects that were created via Cross Org Adapter.

The first external lookup field is for eternal Case object. This field works as expected in both Lightning and Classic, ie. rendered as lookup field, able to lookup cases from the other org.

The second external lookup field is for external Opportunity object. In Classic, this field is rendered as lookup input and working as expected. However, it is rendered as Textbox in Lightning.

I have tried revalidate and sync the cross org adapter, but it didn’t help.

Anyone encountered the same issue?

Comment: I realize it has been 2 years, but I have the same issue, did you ever find a good solution?

Comment: Sadly, nope. We changed it to other approach (can't remember)